# xubuntu 12.04 totally refuses to boot after install with wubi on old computer. any tips or suggestions on things i can do to fix this problem?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, laptop, xubuntu, boot-failure

I downloaded Xubuntu 12.04 32-bit (the desktop CD ISO, not the alternate CD) from [xubuntu.org](http://xubuntu.org/) and placed the .zip into a folder named XUBUNTU on my desktop.

Then I extracted the files to that folder and ran Wubi. I selected Xubuntu from the drop down menu and clicked Install. I let it do it's thing and then chose the option to reboot when prompted. This is when i went to my girlfriend's house for the day and left my laptop (dell latitude 120L) to finish the install. i came back home (about 8 hours later) to find my computer on the windows 7 log in screen when i rebooted my computer once more. I booted Xubuntu just fine and things seemed to work perfectly. I turned off the pc and went to bed. Next morning I booted Xubuntu again without problems.

I rebooted and went to Windows, then next time I tried booting Xubuntu in the middle of the splash screen it went black and the cpu light stopped blinking. I force shut down the computer and tried booting again when the same thing happened (instead of going black the splash just froze). I went back to windows and uninstalled and reinstalled the OS and havent been able to boot it since. I even tried booting Kubuntu with the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: not yet but i am in the process of putting boot-repair on a usb using Lili. i will post updates

Comment: You should not extract file from that zip file. That is ISO file not zip.

@Mitch `boot-repair` works in wubi install??

Comment: even after i placed wubi in a folder with just the iso and ran it i was still having problems

Comment: i have tried every installation method i can think of except for a cd/dvd install and i keep havin the same problem. but when i boot from a usb it takes longer for mycomputer to freeze. also, i have no idea how to use boot-repair because xubuntu wont boot, and idk how to get terminal access to use it. this really sucks and im considering just giving up.

Comment: it wont even boot in live mode!

Answer (score 1):

This almost sounds like a hardware problem.  You might try putting burning a disc or putting it on a flash drive so you can run the memory test that's available as a boot time option.

In the past, I had a computer that ran Windows fine, but could not install linux.  Ended up being bad memory that had to be replaced.